# Dos line endings in my files on Mac OS?

Tags: unix, dos

I'm on Mac OS X, and so is my friend Andy. We both downloaded and installed a python package. My generated `.vim` files had dos line endings (they appeared as `^M` in error messages, and I fixed them using `dos2unix` on each file. He didn't share this problem with line endings. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

What editor did you friend use?

It may be a different setting in his .vimrc (if he's using Vim).